# How to force traffic encryption in SMB v3

Tags: smb, smb3

How traffic encryption can be forced in SMB v3 on Windows 10 Enterprise?

I have already disabled SMB v1 and SMB v2 in the registy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `global encryption` feature to true.

See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2015/09/09/smb-3-1-1-encryption-in-windows-10/) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2012/06/08/encryption-in-smb3/) for more information.